# Where do I change the width from my ul li

Tags: html, css, web

My website looks like the screenshot and I want to change this width from the border so the `<a>` Co2 Scan... fits in one line!

[image]

```css
.wrapper ul li{
  height: 10%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.wrapper ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="active">
  <label for="active" class="menu-btn"><span></span></label>
  <label for="active" class="close"></label>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">CO2 Scan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Infos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rezepte</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please update the CSS with the important parts for your navigation. Not for the whole page, just what's necessary so that we see your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `white-space: nowrap;` for the `<a>` tag:

```css
.wrapper ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
.wrapper ul li {
  height: 10%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="active">
<label for="active" class="menu-btn"><span></span></label>
<label for="active" class="close"></label>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">CO2 Scan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Infos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rezepte</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks now its in one line but not Symmetric to the other borders. I want to Center the text and expand the border width.

Comment: @TheChartChannel Can you post the full CSS - coz what you have given is incomplete.

Comment: I cant, I tried to edit but it always says i have to add more details, too much code.
The CSS file is very big!

Comment: @TheChartChannel Can you post a sandbox link?